# What should I do to set MS CRM to use other identity provider or are there any instructions on that?

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm, claims-based-identity, saml-2.0, federated-identity

Our application uses federated single sign-on authentication process and we already have our identity provider set, up and running. I have the application instance running too, that I would like to integrate to MS CRM using our IdP for authentication.

Do you know if I could get, somewhere, steps on what I should do to set MS CRM to use our IdP (upload our idp.xml ...), I didn't manage to find anything on the CRM official sites?

Our IdP is ForgeRock OpenAM and SAML should be used for communication.

Is it possible at all to use other IdPs but ADFS with MS CRM?

Thank you for the time spent on replying!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the CRM STS supports SAML directly - if it's similar to the SharePoint STS, it doesn't.

The easiest way is to configure CRM with ADFS in the normal way and then federate ADFS with OpenAM. ADFS has full SAML support.

Note that you need to use OpenAM's federation functionality.

Comment: thank you for answering.

We will have to switch to ADFS only, seems much more feasible in the case of our clients.

We have a certain amount of accounts bought from MS CRM online services for our organization. Is it possible to set the CRM for ADFS usage from that position? All the manuals I see are covering stand-alone installations of MS CRM and ADFS related settings are done during the CRM installation. Thank you!